# Calendar show strange data(android)

Tags: android, calendar

Sorry for my english. Many times I try to fix my problem but it's not good for me. I use [ExtendedCalendarView](https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView) library tor show a start date and an end date in calendar. But it shows only the end date, and this not right "2015-10-05" and its all what i see in my calendar. My code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarProvider.COLOR, Event.COLOR_RED);
values.put(CalendarProvider.DESCRIPTION, "Some Description");
values.put(CalendarProvider.LOCATION, "Some location");
values.put(CalendarProvider.EVENT, "Event name");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
cal.set(2015, 8, 2, 0, 0);
values.put(CalendarProvider.START, cal.getTimeInMillis());
int startDayJuliadn = Time.getJulianDay(cal.getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(tz.getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis())));
values.put(CalendarProvider.START_DAY, startDayJuliadn);

cal.set(2015, 9, 5, 0, 0);
int endDayJulian = Time.getJulianDay(cal.getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(tz.getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis())));

values.put(CalendarProvider.END, cal.getTimeInMillis());
values.put(CalendarProvider.END_DAY, endDayJulian);
Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(CalendarProvider.CONTENT_URI,values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your julian start day is incorrect :

see here from the dev github page:

> julian start day is generated for you when the month is built so all
>   you would have to do it call day.getStartDay() on the day and it will
>   give you the julian day

Answer (score 0):

In order to see your date like "2015-10-05" you can use SimpleDateFormat 
like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```